# Browserify bundle.js Error: exec is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify, samba

I recently installed Node.js, npm, samba-client and browserify. The Problem is, that i get an Uncaught TypeError in my bundle.js File and i'm not able to resolve this.

```
bundle.js:107 
    Uncaught TypeError: exec is not a function
    at SambaClient.execute (bundle.js:107)
    at SambaClient.mkdir (bundle.js:58)
    at Object.8.samba-client (bundle.js:1319)
    at s (bundle.js:1)
    at e (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
```

I did some research and found out, that it could be the package.json File that is somewhat wrong.

```
{
  "name": "package.json",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "directories": {
    "lib": "lib"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "child_process": "^1.0.2",
    "debug": "^3.1.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "samba-client": "^2.0.0",
    "util": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

But if i'm honest, i have no clue what to do.

This is the part, where it fails first in bundle.js:

```
SambaClient.prototype.execute = function(cmd, cmdArgs, workingDir, cb) {
  var fullCmd = wrap(util.format('%s %s', cmd, cmdArgs));

  var command = ['smbclient', this.getSmbClientArgs(fullCmd).join(' ')].join(' ');

  var options = {
    cwd : workingDir
  };

  **exec(command, options, function(err, stdout, stderr) {**
    var allOutput = (stdout + stderr);
    if(err !== null) {
      err.message += allOutput;
    }
    cb(err, allOutput);
  });
};
```

Hopefully someone can help me. :)

Comment: Why are you using Browserify on NodeJS code? Or are you trying to use a Samba client from a web browser?

Comment: Exact. I'm trying to use samba-client from a web browser. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it is not and probably never will be. The browser's security model won't allow it. Imagine that a random website could access Samba shares visible to your machine... brrr. What you can do is run a local NodeJS server that does the Samba communication, and have a browser based frontend for that.

Comment: Somehow logical - damn. That was eye-opening. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you import correctly the exec function ?

```
const exec  = require('child_process').exec;
```